# Enable C application as Webservice

Tags: java, c, web-services, java-native-interface

We have an application written in C language which interacts with Oracle database. This application is an executable and runs on unix platform. We need to expose this application over http as web service for others to consume.

I thought of using JNI and CXF for webservice and run the application in tomcat.

Is this a right solution or there are other possibilities?

I found Axis2 supporting C language to write webservice. I have no experience of C language. Is Axis2 in C is good? What http server I can use to deploy the app? Would Apache webserver siffice in this case?

EDIT: The command line is not an option as though I mentioned its an exe but the part which I have to expose don't have any command line available and its bit hard as it needs complicated data structure as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a few factors.  Vinko's method requires the app has a good clean command-line interface.  Further, creating a new process for every webservice request will limit the number of requests that can be serviced.  This may or may not be okay depending on how big the audience is expected to be.

If there's not that great a command-line interface and you want to maximize the number of requests you can serve, that then leaves you two main choices.   Write the web service in Java, and call out to C with JNI or [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/).  Or, write it in pure C or C++.  The last is probably not advisable if the responsible developers don't know any C.

EDIT: Given that command-line is not an option, I recommend Java with JNI or JNA.

Comment: Not knowing C won't be a problem, I can manage that, I only need to what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Apache Foundation package [Axis2/C](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/c/).  It is a pretty solid interface, though it still has slightly limited portability (works out of the box on Linux, but not on Solaris, for example - needs some tweaks).

However, since you say you don't have the experience in C, that may make it too daunting for you.  On the other hand, you say the code you're trying to convert to a web service is in C (plus perhaps Oracle OCI); that means that you are going to find it hard to avoid learning some C to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

After using Axis2/C on the server-side for more than two years, I strongly NOT recommend using Axis2/C for any server-side code for the following reasons:

1. It is full of memory leaks. Namely, service code generated from WSDL leaks, simple HTTP server leaks, CGI module leaks (which is not a problem if you use it as a basic CGI, but a major problem if you use it from FastCGI or similar, or reuse the code). The only part of the HTTP-server code in Axis2/C I didn't check so far is mod_axis2 module for Apache2. Maybe it's better.
2. Axis2/C doesn't have any HTTP server implementation that you could embed easily in your C app: the "simple HTTP server" leaks and it doesn't support HTTP keep-alives (closes connection after every request). I had to implement a server myself based on boost::asio HTTP server examples and Axis2/C CGI module. Spent 1 day on implementation and 4 days to remove all the memory leaks. This proportion seems standard for any Axis2/C-related work. Do you want to spend days and nights with valgrind, debugging memory leaks and double-free's?
3. Most important, the project is NOT actively maintained: there are a lot of issues with patches in their JIRA, but it takes months and years to review and apply the patches. I doubt if any serious project uses it for server-side. My plan in a long-term is to clone it into GIT and maintain the patched version on github (I have to support the code already implemented with Axis2/C for years).

P.S. in my next web-services related subproject I will use JNI to embed Jetty + CXF.

Comment: Axis2/C-1.7.0(trunk) has many new features and completely unstable. So we use 1.6.0. It more stable but it have number of bugs also. We created project on googlecode(https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/) with some patches backported from current trunk. If you have patches, that can improve it's stability, and you ready to contribute into that project, please write me (<my_username_at_stackoverlow>[at]gmail.com).